# Imprimindo ASCII estendido em C

Tags: c, ascii

Vejam este código simpes escrito em C:

```
unsigned char *palavra = "fantástica";
int tamanho = strlen(palavra);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
    printf("%i ", palavra[i]);
printf("\n");
```

Saída obtida: `102 97 110 116 195 161 115 116 105 99 97`

A ideia é apresentar os códigos ASCII de cada sinal gráfico. No entanto, observando a tabela ASCII, o código para "á" deveria ser 160. E ele é exibido como 195 e 161. Como posso resolver essa situação, de forma que "á" resulte em 160?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tabela de caracteres ASCII *(American Standard Code for Information Interchange)* vai até o caractere 127 apenas.

O Termo ASCII estendido é mal usado, [e até criticado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII)<sup><sub>(en)</sub></sup>, pois pode se referir a um monte de tabelas/encodings diferentes, e isto vale até para o Unicode, pois seus primeiros 127 *codepoints* são os mesmos do ASCII.

Resumindo, não existe uma "tabela ASCII estendida", é apenas um termo genérico.

Para dar 160, só depende do codepage que você está usando (ex:CP850 e CP437). Os "caras" usam esse nome só pra dizer que a tabela ASCII original está contida no começo do charset utilizado (como, por exemplo, as páginas de código do DOS, os sets WIN-1252, ISO-8859-1, UTF-8 (que é o que vc está usando), etc.

- **No seu caso específico**, é o seu editor de código que está configurado como UTF-8, e a solução seria trocar o encoding dele ao criar/salvar o arquivo. Um bom teste seria salvar usando um editor do CMD ou Shell do sistema.
- **Se fosse um input** para o usuário digitar, aí dependeria exclusivamente do ambiente, e você teria que configurar seu sistema para a página desejada.